# How difficult is it to replace this tub diverter valve?

Tags: shower, bathtub, diverter

I live in a house built in 2008.  The tub diverter valve no longer stops water from coming out the tub spout when engaged.  You therefore can't take a shower.

I looked under the diverter and there isn't a screw holding it in place.

1. Is the diverter screwed onto the actual pipe?
2. Is it as "simple" as getting a new diverter and screwing that on?

[image: diverter without screw]

[image: shower handle and diverter]

Ok [@JACK](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/104183/jack), here are the after photos and 2 more questions:

3. Is that diverter valve serviceable?  Doesn't look like it comes apart.
4. Is that an adapter on the bare pipe to fit this particular diverter? If so, I take it that I have to either find something that fits or do pipe work for the next valve, correct?

[image: removed diverter]
[image: After removal]

Repair Kit

[image: repair kit]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. Since there's no screw, just turn the spout counterclockwise and remove it from the pipe coming through the wall. Depending on the type of spout you're going to install, you might have to cut the threads off the end of the pipe and tighten the spout in place with the screw on the new spout.

You should be able to spread those plastic strips enough to pull the diverter rod out. Cleaning the inside area and pieces might be all you need to do.

That threaded adapter came with the spout. The threads will be standard but the distances could be different with different spouts.

Comment: Yes turning CCW usually works , run hot water first it helps, since an 2008 I am Shute Jack is right, I have run into a ~mid 60’s home that was sweated at both ends. I made a mess of it before cutting it off and realizing the spout was 1 piece , the only one I ever found like this, so I think jack’s advice is sound.

Comment: Thanks Jack, that worked! I added after photos and questions 3 and 4.  If I should put in a new question I can do that too.

Comment: @drfence  I added more information to my answer.

Comment: @JACK I was able to spread the plastic strips and pull out the diverter rod.  I'm headed to Home Depot later to see if I might find replacement parts. Not super hopeful in this disposable world.  There is the white plastic piece and a washer inside.

Comment: The round hole on the underside near the opening could be provided to allow inserting a screwdriver or manipulator to do something. Examine this carefully. It may be necessary to insert a tool there to install the spout or to service it.

Comment: It could be that there is supposed to be a plastic plug inserted into this small round hole to keep water from flowing out. You wrote that the diverter is not working. Exactly how is it failing to work properly?

Comment: I fixed it by following @JACKs instructions to pull out the diverter rod. I then replaced the black washer inside and voila.  I added a photo of the repair kit above.  I only used the washer out of it.  Using the new white plastic part and washer together didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same faucet. Same type of diverter. I took out the diverter per your and others on YouTube instructions. Wanted to see if lime and scale were causing a bad seal. So I put my finger in there.
What came out stumps me. A chunk, like flat thread of metal. Put it together and it still leaked. So I took it apart again.   Thats when the second sliver fell out. Two slivers of metal. I thought it was the faucet, but I think what I got were two pieces of solder. It works like new now. I'll see how long it lasts, but it operates smooth and really stops all water from running out the faucet and it all comes out the shower head now. It even unlocks when it's turned off and drains out the water from the faucet. I won't have to remember to push it down now. So better than before. Has this ever happened before?
I thought those pieces were a worn out piece inside, but it seems like they were in there since the install. I attached a pic to this alternate answer. [image: pic of metallic strands that came from faucet]